# CORS error not allowing access to API data in react

Tags: reactjs, cors

I am trying to access https api from localhost to access user data. But while trying to do so,I get CORS error even after applying necessary headers configuration.

```
axios.get('https://myURL', 
     { headers: { 'Authorization': AuthStr, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*', 
              'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" } 
               }, { crossDomain: true })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("response",response);
      });
```

Am I missing something ? I tried to refer related links and applied the suggested solution but none of them worked. I am unable to get rid of the following error:

```
Access to XMLhttpsrequest has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Note: When tried to access same URL from Postman, shows the data correctly.
Please help!

Comment: Not knowing anything else about your setup this is more likely an issue with the cors setting at `https://myURL` than the cors headers of the request.

Comment: Does the API allow requests from localhost?

Comment: CORS headers need to be set by the _server_, not the client.

Comment: Same request when tried to access from Postman works. So I am guessing issue is from the client side.

Answer (score -1):

The CORS headers are not so important in the request.  The CORS headers must be issued in the response.

The server is the one which decides from which CORS origins to take requests.

So the solution is to configure the endpoints at the server to return the right CORS policy headers in the response.

The key here is which headers is the server returning to the client not which headers the client is sending to the server.

Comment: If you area going to downvote at least make it constructive by expressing why you downvoted... Otherwise it contributes very little to finding the right anwer.